# Simulate an AR(1) process with uniform innovations

Tags: r, time-series

I need to plot an `AR(1)` graph for the process

```
y[k] = 0.75 * y[k-1] + e[k] for y0 = 1.
```

Assume that `e[k]` is uniformly distributed on the interval `[-0.5, 0.5]`.

I am trying to use `arima.sim`:

```
library(tseries)
y.0 <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=.75), n=100)
plot(y.0)
```

It does not seem correct. Also, what parameters do I change if `y[0] = 10`?

Comment: Hi @ZheyuanLi, do i need to add in rand() to ensure the uniform distribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want to use R base function `arima.sim` for this task, and no extra libraries are required.

By default, `arima.sim` generates ARIMA with innovations ~ `N(0,1)`. If we want to change this, we need to control the `rand.gen` or `innov` argument. For example, you want innovations from uniform distributions `U[-0.5, 0.5]`, we can do either of the following:

```
arima.sim(model=list(ar=.75), n=100, rand.gen = runif, min = -0.5, max = 0.5)

arima.sim(model=list(ar=.75), n = 100, innov = runif(100, -0.5, 0.5))
```

---

**Example**

```
set.seed(0)
y <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=.75), n = 100, innov = runif(100, -0.5, 0.5))
ts.plot(y)
```

[image]

---

In case we want to have explicit control on `y[0]`, we can just shift the above time series such that it starts from `y[0]`. Suppose `y0` is our desired starting value, we can do

```
y <- y - y[1] + y0
```

For example, starting from `y0 = 1`:

```
y <- y - y[1] + 1
ts.plot(y)
```

[image]

Comment: what parameters do i change if y0=10 instead of y0=1?

Comment: hi @ZheyuanLi how come you do not need to convert to uniform distribution for the second solution?

Comment: yes. There is no innov or rand.gen in the second solution where we rearrange the equation to have control over y(0)