# Recursive calculation of a simulated variable

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to simulate a variable and it's supposed to work like this:

```
v[t] = Q * v[t-1] + e[t]
```

`e` is a random error I generate using `rnorm(156,0,0.001)`; `v` is what I aim to simulate; `Q` is a coefficient (I'm using 0.5).

The 1st value `v[1]` would be equal to `e[1]`. Then

```
v[2] = Q * v[1] + e[2]
v[3] = Q * v[2] + e[3]
. . .
```

I'm new to R, I'm trying to use a `for` loop but I'm struggling (I was going to publish my code here but it isn't working so I thought I wouldn't waste people's time). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, you should publish the code you have so far

Comment: Yes, please give data and code to make this reproducible

Comment: Sorry, will do it next time. The answers below are comprehensive and to the point, though, so thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typical autoregressive process, which can be generated using of `filter` with "recursive" method.

```
e <- rnorm(156, 0, 0.001)
filter(x = c(0, e), filter = 0.5, method = "recursive")[-1]
```

Let's consider a small example with length 5 only:

```
set.seed(0)

e <- rnorm(5, 0, 0.1)
# [1]  0.12629543 -0.03262334  0.13297993  0.12724293  0.04146414

x <- filter(x = c(0, e), filter = 0.5, method = "recursive")

x[-1]
# [1] 0.12629543 0.03052438 0.14824212 0.20136399 0.14214614
```

---

`filter` is the workhorse of `arima.sim`, however, it is simply a computational routine with written C code and does not require the process to be stationary. Readers interested in `arima.sim` may continue to read:

- [Simulate a time series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40922194/4891738)
- [Simulate an AR(1) process with uniform innovations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39925470/4891738)

Answer (score 1):

We note that the unit response to the auto-regressive process `v(t)=Q*v(t-1) + u(t)` is:

```
unit_res <- c(1, Q, Q^2, Q^3, ...)
```

We can generate this response using `unit_res <- q^(seq_len(length(err))-1)`. Then, the response `v` to `err` is simply the convolution of `err` with this `unit_res`:

```
set.seed(123) ## for reproducibility
q <- 0.5
err <- rnorm(156,0,0.0001)
unit_res <- q^(seq_len(length(err))-1)
## first (initial value is zero) and we take the first 156 values from the convolution
v <- c(0, convolve(err,rev(unit_res),type="open")[1:156])
##head(v,20)
## [1]  0.000000e+00 -5.604756e-05 -5.104153e-05  1.303501e-04  7.222587e-05  4.904171e-05
## [7]  1.960274e-04  1.441053e-04 -5.445347e-05 -9.591202e-05 -9.252221e-05  7.614708e-05
##[13]  7.405492e-05  7.710461e-05  4.962057e-05 -3.077383e-05  1.633044e-04  1.314372e-04
##[19] -1.309431e-04  4.664044e-06
```

Since `156` is not a large number, another way to do this is to construct a unit response matrix for the difference equation `v(t)=Q*v(t-1) + err(t)` of the form:

```
Z = [1   0   0   0   ...
     Q   1   0   0   ...
     Q^2 Q   1   0   ...
     Q^3 Q^2 Q   1   ...
     ... ... ... ... ...]
```

This matrix will be `156 x 156` in your case. Note that each column of this matrix is the response in time to a unit input in `err` at time `t` equaling to the column index. Since the system is linear, the response `v` to `err=rnorm(156,0,0.001)` is given by superposition of each individual unit response and can be computed by matrix multiplication `v = Z %*% err`.

To construct this matrix, we can use the function:

```
constructZ <- function(Q, N) {
  r <- Q^(seq_len(N)-1)
  m <- matrix(rep(r,N),nrow=N)
  z <- matrix(0,nrow=N,ncol=N)
  z[lower.tri(z,diag=TRUE)] <- m[row(m) <= (N+1-col(m))]
  z
}
```

With this we have:

```
v <- c(0,constructZ(q, length(err)) %*% err)
```

which gives the same result.